# Counting number of cells to next occurance

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of about 5000 items.  Each item is labeled a number between 1-5. The first item in this list is a 1. I would like to identify each time there is a 1, and then count how many cells follow that until there is another 1. I then want to sum the values associated with each cell to find a "total" for each cell labeled with 1.

Say my table looks like this (We would be looking at column 3):

```
+-----+----+---+
| 20  | A  | 1 |
| 30  | B  | 2 |
| 10  | C  | 2 |
| 20  | D  | 3 |
| 50  | E  | 2 |
| 30  | F  | 1 |
| 40  | G  | 2 |
| 40  | H  | 3 |
| 10  | I  | 5 |
| 50  | J  | 1 |
+-----+----+---+
```

In row A the summation would be the sum of A-E, 130.
In row F the summation would be the sum of F-I, 120.

The only part of this I need answered is what the syntax would be to count the number of rows from A-E in this sittuation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative with Index. Offset is volatile and will cause a recalculation of the whole sheet any time **any** cell changes. With large datasets that can cause slowness.

Index is not volatile. You can use:

```
=IF(C1=1,SUM(A1:INDEX(A2:$A$9999,MATCH(1,C2:$C$9999,0)-1)),"")
```

To ensure that the last result of the formula is correct, add a "1" value in a row below your source data in the same column ("C")

**Note:** This is also required if you want to use the Offset variation with a range that is larger than the current data set. Otherwise both formulas will not find a final "1" and will return #N/A.

And there is another problem with the Offset formula and a fixed range. The current application of the formula

```
=IF(C1=1,SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,MATCH(1,C2:$C$10,0))),"")
```

and then copied down to row 10 will result in this formula in row 10:

```
=IF(C10=1,SUM(OFFSET(A10,0,0,MATCH(1,C$10:$C11,0))),"")
```

If the data range of the source data is not fixed, you would need to manipulate the last row of the formula before copying it down further.

Comment: I didn't know about the issue with `OFFSET()` causing recalculation... Definite +1!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to put, in cell `D1` the following formula:

```
=IF(C1=1,SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,MATCH(1,C2:$C$10,0))),"")
```

(Obviously update the `$C$10` to the end of your dataset) and drag this down

Basically, what you're saying is:

- If column C has a 1 then:

  - Take the Sum of Column A starting at my row and going all the way down until you match the next value of `1`
- Or Else return `""`

This relies on the fact that the `Match()` function will return the first time it finds a match and so it starts at the row directly after yours (`C2` and continues looking for the next value of `1`all the way down until the bottom of your dataset - In this case, `$C$10`)

Hope that makes sense and does the trick!